# Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.):- Nodejs 13 with Django

Tags: node.js, reactjs, django

I am trying to send an HTTP POST request from my frontend in Node.js 13 to my Django backend, but I keep getting the error "Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set)."

Currently, the application is configured to send an API request to my server to obtain the csrf_token when I open the website.

Then, I attempted to send an API request to register with the csrf_token, but encountered the aforementioned error.

```
    const respond = await fetch(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/register_user/',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken,
            },

            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: name,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                passport: passport,
                trustNode: trustNode,
            }),
            cache: 'no-cache',
        }
    );
```

This is my Django settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'website_backend',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
]


CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
    
]
```